# Compact Hausdorff space, hereditarily Lindelöf but non-metrizable?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, cardinals

Is there a compact Hausdorff space that is  hereditarily Lindelöf but non-metrizable? Under the continuum Hypothesis, such space exists (see the abstract of *A compact L-space under CH* by Kunen). I would what if we assume the opposite of  the continuum Hypothesis.

From the abstract of *Locally connected hereditarily Lindelöf compacta*, it seems that such space exists with the negation of the continuum Hypothesis. But I don't understand the notation $MA$ and $CH$ therein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Double Arrow Space](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces/S000093); questions like these may be answered by searching the pi-Base: [https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Compact%2B%24T_2%24%2BHereditarily%20Lindel%C3%B6f%2B~Metrizable](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Compact%2B%24T_2%24%2BHereditarily%20Lindel%C3%B6f%2B%7EMetrizable)

In particular it's a compact separable linearly orderable topological space, and thus Hausdorff and hereditarily Lindelöf. But it's non-metrizable because it's not second-countable.

Comment: Dear @StevenClontz, Thank you! Pi-Base is a cool website.